# Named router outlet - Parent navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a router outlet set up like this sitename/module/:moduleId/(child:childId)..

**I would now like to navigate to the parent route from the outlet using an anchor tag and a routerLink like this [routerlink] = ['../../']. Unfortunately this doesn't work with a named router outlet.**

What currently works is that i access the parent snapshot, get the moduleId from the query parameters and then this .. [routerLink] = "['/module',moduleId]"

Is this doable with just an anchor tag and routeLink instead of having to use javascript.

Expected Code in Component A (HTML):

```
<a [routerLink]="['../../']">Back To parent</a>
```

Working code in Component A(HTML) :

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/module',moduleId]"> Back to parent </a>
```

ComponentB:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.moduleId = this.activatedRoute.parent.snapshot.paramMap.get('moduleType');
}
```

App module

```
{
  path: ':moduleId', component: ComponentA, children: [{
    path: ':childId', component: ComponentB, outlet: 'child'
  }]
}
```

ComponentA:

```
<router-outlet name="child"></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Edited.. Does this help?